# Generating XML serialization assemblies in x86 targeted mode

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

Usually I have no problem ticking the box that generates serialization assemblies for my .Net code.

However, I just changed by platform target to 'x86' instead of 'Any CPU' to fix some problems when running on x64 architecture.

Now, I get the error that Trigger.XMLSerialization.dll references Trigger.dll [version=0.0.0.0 culture=neutral]

Is there a known fix to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a bug in the SQL Server CLR support for platform-targeted assemblies.  No fix available :(

See [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=361684&wa=wsignin1.0).

Answer (score 0):

Does it error if you use `sgen` directly at the command line?

Comment: Hmm, I just used .Net inspector and it seems that the reference is actually correct, but when I load it into MS SQL using CREATE ASSEMBLY, then it gets the version wrong - 0.0.0.0